# Recording internal Body sounds for a Soundinstallation

Tags: sound-design

I've already searched the forum but couldn't find a solution to my problem yet.

I'm currently working on an installation for a sound art festival and would like to make my body sounds audible, i.e. heart, lungs, swallow sounds etc.. I've been experimenting with a construction of stethoscopes and lavalier microphones for a while now and actually achieve quite good results.
My main problem is that I get feedback problems and actually want to run the installation at a certain volume, which I just can't reach at the moment.

I am using these mics Movo LV8-C XLR Lavalier Kardioid Kondensator Mikrofon: Amazon.de: Elektronik 
Maybe you have some ideas what might solve the problem. Other microphones? Plugins?

I am running the Mics through Ableton Live via a Focusrite Clarett 8 Pre.
Thanks and Greetings from Berlin

Answer (score 2):

You may want to [look into something like this](https://ekohealth.com/shop/core-attachment/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Shopping&gclid=CjwKCAjwyOreBRAYEiwAR2mSknN_IySchGEymQr0i1Iyc8pkhKpCqq7B-74kzN7Y8M099WhGzCimmxoCqggQAvD_BwE) or [this](https://www.medicaldevicedepot.com/Thinklabs-One-Digital-Stethoscope-p/TH-TL1001.htm?dfw_tracker=3918-22356&gclid=CjwKCAjwyOreBRAYEiwAR2mSkvibgyEsFDzbCeEPvKuMjjpxCMuLcZNlHG3nYcfGeFwkxLqY6rX9XRoC50QQAvD_BwE) or other similar commercially available units since you need something that works in the range of human body sounds most "electronic stethoscopes" should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are amplifying faint audio sounds that you are picking up with a sensitive audio device... So it will pick up the amplified sounds as well and lead you into feedback territory.

Two simple solutions for combating feedback:

- EQ the feedback away - find out what frequency your feedback is on and ramp it down
- Use lower gain - if you can place your mic or device closer to the source of sounds then you don't need to amplify so much which means lower likelihood of feedback

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to remove yourself further from the speakers? ie. Can you be in a separate room or behind a partition? Sometimes drummers will enclose themselves in a plexiglass booth, perhaps you could try something similar?